# 'Screen -h num ' not working on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnu-screen

I am logged into my remote server using ssh and then running a process using `screen`.
I started a screen session using `screen -h 5000` so that I can scroll up the screen to see the console output. But all the output is lost and I am not able to retrieve it. I can't scroll up the screen to see the output.

What can be done to see the complete output?

I cannot dump the output in a file because it will take lot of space and there is not much of it remained on server.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to scroll in screen using the key combination Ctrl-A Esc (so first Ctrl-A, release, press Escape). This enables copy mode. After you completed scrolling, you can cancel copy mode with another Esc.